# "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" message when root view is being set

Tags: ios, appdelegate, launching-application

I have the following code in my App Delegate file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MBFeedViewController *feedViewController = [[MBFeedViewController alloc] init];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:feedViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Then when I run my app, the console outputs the message:

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Can't figure this one out.  `FeedViewController` is not `nil` when I set the window's `RootViewController`.

Comment: What's in your `main.m`?

Comment: @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MBAppDelegate class]));
    }

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I am not using storyboard

Answer (score 3):

> Can't figure this one out. feedViewController is not nil when I set
>   the window's rootviewcontroller.

Make sure that you're properly initializing your view controller. It's most common to use the designated initializer, `-initWithNibName:bundle:`. H2CO3 points out that `init` is okay too. Either way, make sure that you're also initializing the superclass by calling `[super initWithNibName:... bundle:...]` or just `[super init]`.

Next, make sure that `feedViewController.view` isn't nil. When you set the window's root view controller, the window will install that controller's view as its own content. A view controller normally creates its view the first time it's `view` property is accessed, so there's no reason that you should ever get `nil` there unless creating the view fails.

Finally, try instantiating a plain old `UIViewController` and setting *that* as the window's root view controller. Do you get the same warning? If yes, perhaps you've stumbled on a bug. If no, look carefully at `MBFeedViewController`, especially the initializer(s), `-loadView`, `-viewDidLoad` and other methods that are called early in the life of the view controller.

Comment: Using `init` with `UIViewController` is just fine. It calls `initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil`.

Comment: Start a new single-view project without using storyboards, go to app delegate implementation and change `self.viewController = [[XXViewController alloc] initWithNibName:bundle:]` to `[[XXViewController alloc] init]`. You won't get a view, but also you won't get an error output.

Comment: @H2CO3 Didn't realize that. It's not documented on the UIViewController reference page, but I see that the header file says: *(As a convenience, the default init method will do this for you, and specify nil for both of this methods arguments.)*

Comment: @Caleb The essence is in the details ;-)

Comment: @H2CO3 That kind of thing is the reason I stick around here.

Comment: feedViewController.view isn't nil and I am calling [super init] in ffeedViewController's init method

Comment: Also I am not using nib files.

Comment: @NSNolan You can still call `-initWithNibName:bundle:` if you're not using a nib file -- just pass `nil` for the name and bundle parameters. If we believe the comment in UIViewController.h you shouldn't have to change that, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @NSNolan Added a few more ideas above.

Comment: @Caleb, your ideas lead me to figure out that it is an asynchronous network call in my viewDidLoad method that is causing this message to prompt itself.  Do you know of a reason why that would be the case?

Comment: @NSNolan, are you sure that's the cause? I tried to duplicate this, with a long running async process in viewDidLoad, but couldn't get your error message.